# How to convert a 10-Watt solar panel into 3v & 3 amp?

Tags: voltage, solar-cell, watts, amperage

The device I use requires about 3V and 3 amps.

Based on my Google research, I found out that in order to get 3V and 3 amps from a solar panel, the solar panel needs to be at least 9 watts.

So let's say I purchase a solar panel that outputs 10 watts.

Can I simply find an adapter cord, cut its tail, connect the tail to the solar panel directly and then connect the whole thing to the device?

Will it work?

Comment: Only if that is the output voltage of the panel under the conditions at which you will be using it.  Likely it's highly variable.  You'll likely need at least a DC-DC buck and/or boost converter to get the desired output voltage, and you may also want to add a battery to account for varying conditions.

Comment: You will in practice need at least 30W of solar power, and if you can not handle a second of no power now and then, a battery/ultra capacitor. And also a switched DC-DC regulator so that you can decrease the voltage and increase the current.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From an ebay auction for a 10-Watt solar panel:

[image]

Though it's not easy to see, look at the specifications.

(1) 10W is the *maximum* power, i.e., expect considerably less under less than optimum conditions

(2) The output voltage at maximum power is 17.3V, far more than the 3V your device requires.

(3) The maximum current output is about 0.72A, far less than the 3A your device requires.

> will it work ?

Only in movies where, evidently, any power source will magically have the correct voltage and current to run any device in a pinch.

The lesson here is that the maximum power rating is just that, the maximum power the panel can produce.

As Chris Stratton points out, unless your device can handle the nominal output voltage of the panel and can work over a wide variation from that nominal voltage, you'll need to connect the solar panel to an efficient DC-DC converter with the proper voltage output and current capability for your device.

Answer (score 0):

I saw somewhere an answer to a question that seemed to apply quite usefully to your question.
I'm posting it here with slight modification. Note that this is not my work - just seems mainly useful.

**Comments in [square brackets] are mine.**

---

[These are all good points worth noting that many people miss]

> To get 9W out of a 10W panel you need bright mid-day sun, the panel must be clean AND pointed towards the Sun and 90% SMPS efficient Buck Regulator that utilizes the 17.3V max power level of the array.

---

[worth noting]

> Not all SMPS will do this as the switching current can be much higher than the average current thus drop your PV Array well below Vmax power, so more Power management design is required, such as a 17.5V battery design to regulate the input voltage. If you don't , you will be lucky to get 5W.

[Here is a useful [TI web bench simulation](http://webench.ti.com/webench5/power/webench5.cgi?base_pn=TPS54526&Flavor=None&AppType=None&topology=Buck&optFactor=4&VinMin=15&VinMax=17.8&O1I=3&O1V=3&op_TA=30&application=SWITCHER) that somebody has set up that matches your need.]

> You also want an Econo mode for cloudy days for more efficiency.
>
> The [TPS54526](http://webench.ti.com/webench5/power/webench5.cgi?base_pn=TPS54526&Flavor=None&AppType=None&topology=Buck&optFactor=4&VinMin=15&VinMax=17.8&O1I=3&O1V=3&op_TA=30&application=SWITCHER) is one good solution.